# Adding Proxy To X Ray Node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing a node js application and I am scraping a web site using x-ray and I think the blocked my ip address so how can I configure a proxy or hide my Ip address for that ? Here is my code:

```
var Xray = require('x-ray');
var x = Xray()
x('https://www.myurl.com',  {


    title: x('#cm_cr-review_list .a-section.review', [{,
        blogs:"..a-text-bold"
    }]),
})
    .paginate('li.a-l a@href')
    .write('result.json')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think, that there is some Proxy Support.

Maybe try this (no xray)

```
var request = require('superagent');
require('superagent-proxy')
(request);

request
.get('http://google.com/')
.proxy('socks://localhost:9050')
.end(function(err, res) {
if (err) throw err;
console.log(res.text);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I received an  Error: Negotiation Error at Socket.handshake